# mosquitto ACL file, restrict multiple users to same topic

Tags: acl, mosquitto

which is the right syntax for adding several users to same topic restriction?

for example:

```
user user1
topic topic1/#

user user2
topic topic1/#
```

or

```
user user1
user user2
topic topic1/#
```

?

Answer (score 1):

The first option.

You need to list the topics for each user, if you have lots of users it may be easier to use a plugin to load the ACL from a database, or generate the ACL response based on a set of rules.